# Read multiple values from array dynamically in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, dynamic

I have an array of structures.
I'm trying to select several records from the array, that match some condition.
I know there's this option: (For example array `A` with field `f1`):

```
A([A.f1]==5)
```

Which would return all the records that have `f1 = 5`.
But I want to do it for several different fields, in a loop. I saved the fields names in a cell array, but I don't know how to do the same with a dynamic field name.
I know there's the 'getfield' function, but it only selects a field from a single structure.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access dynamically a field of a structure:

```
% Create example structure
s.a = 1;
s.b = 2;

% Suppose you retrieve the fieldnames (or hardcode them fnames = {'a','b'})
fnames = fieldnames(s);
```

The you can retrieve e.g. the second one:

```
s.(fnames{2})
```

In a loop

```
for f = 1:numel(fnames)
    s.(fnames{f})
end
```

In your case:

```
A([A.(fnames{ii})] == n)
```

Comment: Thanks! that's just what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

This code will run through the first 5 records of your dynamical names

```
for i=1:5
   eval(['A([A.' cell_array{i} ']==5)'])
end
```

Comment: This works, but it's bad practice to use `eval` because (a) it's slow, and (b) it's not safe (e.g. what if `cell_array{i}` contains the string `'a]); system(''rm -rf /''); (['`? (NB I disagree with your answer, but I didn't downvote it).